# Is there a way to get the index position for Bootstrap 3 Carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am just following the example on the Bootstrap 3 docs and everything is working fine but I want to be able to know which slide is the active slide (or its position). I saw a number of methods for jumping to a slide but nothing that tells you what the current slide is.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This might be one way

If you want the index, assuming your id of your div tag containing carousel is the same as the example

```
$("#carousel-example-generic .carousel-indicators .active").data('slide-to');
```

With give you the index of what slide is currently being used with 0 as the first

If you want the active slide itself in jQuery,

```
$("#carousel-example-generic .carousel-inner .active img");
```

And that will give you the current slide being shown

I'm sure there are other ways as well.

Hope this helps

Comment: I had actually tried that same approach but it was returning null each time. With some more digging around on here I found a link to this issue on the github repo https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/2404#issuecomment-4589229 and ultimately found this line $('#carousel-features').data("bs.carousel").getActiveIndex() which works perfectly.

Comment: Awesome man, I don't know why you're was returning null, but glad your solution works as well!